# Angular8: Why don't I get space between these Angular Material cards?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I am learning Angular 8 and must now ask what am I doing wrong because there should be space between these cards, the picture below show a red line where there should be some space.

[image]

Here is my **Component html**

```
<mat-card class="mat-space-bottom">
  <mat-card-header><mat-card-title>Book Search Api</mat-card-title></mat-card-header>
  <form [formGroup]="newContact" class="form-container">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Title"  formControlName="title" #box (keyup.enter)="getTitle(box.value)"> <p>{{value}}</p>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Author" formControlName="author" #box (keyup.enter)="getAutor(box.value)"> <p>{{value}}</p>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Genre" formControlName="genre" #box (keyup.enter)="getGenre(box.value)"> <p>{{value}}</p>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Price" formControlName="price" #box (keyup.enter)="getPrice(box.value)"> <p>{{value}}</p>
    </mat-form-field>

  </form>

</mat-card>


<mat-card class="mat-space-bottom" *ngFor="let phone of bookItems">

  <mat-card-header >
    <!-- <div mat-card-avatar class="firstLetter">{{phone.title | slice:0:1 | uppercase}}</div> -->
    <mat-card-title>{{phone.title | titlecase}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{phone.description}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{phone.author}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{phone.genre}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{phone.publish_date}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{phone.price}}</mat-card-subtitle>

  </mat-card-header>
  <!--
  <mat-card-actions>
    <a title="Edit Contact" routerLink="/contact/{{phone.id}}">
      <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
    </a>
    <a class="delete" title="Delete Contact" (click)="delete(phone, phone.id)">
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </a>
  </mat-card-actions>
  </div> -->
</mat-card>
```

Here is my **scss**:

```
mat-card {
  display: flex;
}

mat-card-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

mat-card-actions {
  margin-left: auto;
}

mat-card-subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

mat-card:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

mat-card-actions {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.firstLetter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

mat-card:nth-child(1n) .firstLetter {
  background: #2e6da4;
}

mat-card:nth-child(2n) .firstLetter {
  background: #4cae4c;
}

mat-card:nth-child(3n) .firstLetter {
  background: #46b8da;
}

mat-card:nth-child(4n) .firstLetter {
  background: #eea236;
}

mat-card:nth-child(5n) .firstLetter {
  background: #d43f3a;
}

.delete i {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d43f3a;
}

.mat-space-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: stackblitz code?

Comment: I try the stackblitz [now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vae2yh). I use a ASP.NET Core for backend Crud calls, can stackblitz mock that? Im my project you search for books, Only search for Title works for now, but stackblitz should connect using CRUD but nothing happens, guess I must set up a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to replicate the issue on stackblitz... maybe you're missing something;

kindly check [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6ktsb?file=app/card-fancy-example.html)

I used your HTML/CSS, following is the relevant **ts** file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-fancy-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-fancy-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-fancy-example.css'],
})
export class CardFancyExample {
  bookItems:any[];
  newContact = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(''),
    author: new FormControl(''),
    genre: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
  });

  constructor(){
    this.bookItems = [
      { title:'test title' ,description:'test descr ' ,author:'test author' ,genre:'test1 genre' ,publish_date:'test date' ,price:'test price' }
      ,{ title:'test title' ,description:'test descr ' ,author:'test author' ,genre:'test1 genre' ,publish_date:'test date' ,price:'test price' }
      ,{ title:'test title' ,description:'test descr ' ,author:'test author' ,genre:'test1 genre' ,publish_date:'test date' ,price:'test price' }
      ,{ title:'test title' ,description:'test descr ' ,author:'test author' ,genre:'test1 genre' ,publish_date:'test date' ,price:'test price' }
      ,{ title:'test title' ,description:'test descr ' ,author:'test author' ,genre:'test1 genre' ,publish_date:'test date' ,price:'test price' }
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: You can share your appreciation by accepting the answer and voting it up... cheers :)

Comment: My project derives from a "search for contacts" project, I just copy past learning..

Comment: You stackblitz looks grate easy but I went through your stackblitz trying to apply it on my project but I cant get the same result as your stackblitz show, any ide?, There´s no differences in card-fancy-example.html from mine, I check the styles.css

Comment: are you using the same versions of the npm packages as I?

Comment: My @angular/... was like 8.0.0 and yours are 8.0.1 and some more changes, I update my project but still no change

Comment: if you do inspect element at the place where you put a red line... what do you see? comparing to the stackblitz and your own code?